# Using Push Notications in Strongloop

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to add push notification support to a REST server build in Strongloop / Loopback.  I have followed the instructions at http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Push+notifications, but it fails.  It seems to be due to the line that reads var db = require('./data-sources/db'); this doesn't exist in my loopback installation (perhaps it is documentation related to an older version)?

I can get the sample server running, but trying to get it going in my application has eluded me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc is outdated (I'll fix it).  That way of getting the data source is based on the old structure of the push example.  You will need to get a handle on your data source differently; typically something like

```
var datasource = app.datasources.db;
```

See [Working with LoopBack objects](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Working+with+LoopBack+objects#WorkingwithLoopBackobjects-Workingwithdatasourceobjects) for more information.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the response.  But is seems more complex than just this...  I managed to get it working in the end, but to do so I had to:  -copy the notification.json, installation.json and application.json files from the example to my common/models directory  -add a new datasource into my datasources.json file for "push" (again, copied from the example)  - add various lines to my model-config.json file for application, installation, notification and push  Perhaps I did this the hard way, but its the only solution I could find.

Comment: I would use server-2.0 with loopback 2.x ....it's a new example.  I would use that as your starting point.  The docs IMHO could use alot more seasoning, but they're probably busy trying to put out a product.  Still a beta product I believe.